# Animate material with a sound

Tags: materials

I've already learned how to animate physic transformations with sound curves (scale, position...baking sound to F-Curve) but I wondered how to do the same thing with material (set a keyframe for the intensity of emission shader and then animate with the frequency of a wave sound) can I manage this with nodes (like object info? If the scale of my object is 200% then the intensity of my shader will be 100%) For instance: if the frequency of the wave sound is 100Hz the intensity of the emssion is 1...or, if the frequency is 1000Hz then the colour should be red or like so?

Answer (score 2):

You must use drivers: a driver lets you control any datablock with any other parameter of the software.

Comment: Could you explain why and how? This is not helpful to many users as is.

Comment: Drivers are too complex to explain in  few words. I think this is a great tutorial about them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMoBFzXFAUM

Comment: Excellent, that should help people out.

Comment: Also this internal link can be very helpful:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28254/is-it-possible-to-combine-shape-key-values-from-different-objects